# Specify relation between generic types

Tags: typescript

```
type t = {
    a:{
        c:number
    },
    b:{
        d:boolean
    }
    //...
}

function f1<Section extends {[key:string]:{}},Key extends string>(param1:Key,param2:Section[Key]){}

f1<t,'a'>('a',{c:1})
```

I would specify a relation between `Section` and `Key` generic types such that `Key` is `keyof T` (as I did) **but** let typescript ifer the `Key` type from the first paramter that the user specify.

As a result, I would like to write this line instead:

```
f1<t>('a',{c:1})
```

---

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't specify just some type arguments while letting the compiler infer the rest, this is not supported (there was a proposal to support partial argument inference but it doesn't seem like it will see the light of day any time soon).

The only way to do what you what is to use a curried function approach:

```
type t = {
    a: {
        c: number
    },
    b: {
        d: boolean
    }
    //...
}

function f1<Section extends { [key: string]: {} }>() {
    return function <Key extends string>(param1: Key, param2: Section[Key]) { }
}

f1<t>()('a', { c: 1 })
```

Comment: @StavAlfi This is the PR for it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349